# Javascript- removeEventListener not applied to array, from previous addEventListener added with for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

I've given a lot of thought and troubleshooting to this issue, but cannot see where the error is.

I have some code that adds a click event listener to a bunch of divs.
The event listener is added using a `for` loop, which is applied as expected.

Then, after the click events have been used, I want to remove the event listener, using another `for` loop, and surprisingly it does not work.

Here is my js code:

```
var divElems = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");

for(var i=0; i < divElems.length; i++) {
    divElems[i].addEventListener("click", circleClicked(i), false);
}
... // perform actions with click

function circleClicked(i) {
    return function(){
        console.log("Clicked circle " + i);
    };
}
... 
function removeEvListener() {
    for(var i=0; i < divElems.length; i++) {
        divElems[i].removeEventListener("click", circleClicked(i), false);
    }
}
```

That should be applied on this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle">Circle 1</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 2</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 3</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 4</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 5</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 6</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 7</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 8</div>
    <div class="circle">Circle 9</div>
    <div class="circle empty"></div>
    <div class="circle empty"></div>
</div>
```

The `removeEvListener` function is applied as a callback within the code, as part of an object of options: `{option1: "value1", option2: value2, onComplete: removeEvListener}`

I tried using just the reference, and also with the parentheses `removeEvListener()` and does not work.

The function added to the event listener accepts an input that relates to the index, which is used to identify the actual div being clicked.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `removeEventListener` takes a reference to the event handler function. In your case the function `circleClicked` creates a new function every time it's invoked, therefore you can't pass it to the `removeEventListener`.

There are two solutions:

1. store the references to your event listeners in an array (ugly)
2. create some more generic event handlers. If you really need to access the index of an element you can store it in the `data-` attribute. Or calculate it on demand.

//Edit

`divElems` contains all clickable elements, so in your click handler you could just check the index of the clikced element. In order to be able to easily handle this you can convert NodeList `divElems` to an array

```
var divElementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(divElems);
function clickHandler(e) {
    // e parameter is the click event object, 
    // it has currentTarget property which would be a reference to the div element
    var index = divElementsArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    console.log("Clicked circle's index: " + index);
}
```

Comment: Hi @strah, can you elaborate a bit more on #2 ? The bit about calculating the index on demand is what seems a bit obscure to me now.

Comment: I added an explanation how you could calculate the index 'on the flight'

Comment: I applied the edited explanation and it worked perfectly. Cheers!